# Credit card fraud preventions

Tags: credit-card

Ok lets say some one have clone my debit card here in Greece all debit cards have and stripe and chip and lets say in a way he knows my pin and all my information and he put the info on a blank card can he take my money? i repeate here in greece all banks have chip

Answer (score 2):

This should probably be closed as a duplicate, but given the sheer volume of duplicates, I figured I'd list them in an answer instead of a comment (to make them fit, and for readability) for posterity:

- [Bank cards - chips vs mag stripe security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49306/bank-cards-chips-vs-mag-stripe-security)
- [Why are chips safer than magnetic stripes?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49234/why-are-chips-safer-than-magnetic-stripes)
- [Why does my debit card have a stripe AND a chip?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55157/why-does-my-debit-card-have-a-stripe-and-a-chip)
- [What are the problems that Chip card technology solve? and what are the problems EMV solve? …](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53689/what-are-the-problems-that-chip-card-technology-solve-and-what-are-the-problems)
- [Why EMV cards cannot be cloned?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46319/why-emv-cards-cannot-be-cloned/46322#46322)

These, and many more interesting posts, can be found using the search interface in the upper right hand corner.